# Search in several models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two model classes as follows that are related to each other with `User` class.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    ...
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False) 


class Company(models.Model): 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    code = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
```

And now a `request` comes as follows:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/search/users/?first_name=john&&last_name=dev&&code=25
```

How can I search if one of the input parameters is in one of the tables (person or company)?

> The effort I have made but no result found:
>
> ```
> class SearchUserAPI(APIView):
>     def get(self, request, format=None):
>         try:
>             from django.db.models import Q
>
>             q = request.query_params
>
>             search_models = [Person, Company]
>             search_results = []
>             for model in search_models:
>                 fields = [x for x in model._meta.fields if isinstance(x, django.db.models.CharField)]
>                 search_queries = [Q({x.name + "__icontains": q.get(x.name)}) for x in fields]
>                 print(search_queries)
>                 q_object = Q()
>                 for query in search_queries:
>                     q_object = q_object | query
>                 results = model.objects.filter(q_object)
>                 search_results.append(results)
>                 
>             data = [search_results]
>
>             return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
>
>         except Exception as e:
>             return Response({"error": e}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
> ```

Comment: maybe [`SearchFilter`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter) ?

Comment: In your answer to request must be only person models? Or company models too?

Comment: Why don't you give a try?

Comment: @ТаалайДюшебеков Each table should be searched and if one of the input parameters is found in one of the tables, the user id (Parent table) should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

you can use filterset in drf
I assume your user is somehow linked with person or company in Foreign key or One to one

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters, BaseInFilter

class SearchFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    first_name = filters.CharFilter(
        field_name="person__first_name",
        label='person name'
    )
    last_name = filters.CharFilter(
            field_name="person__first_name",
            label='person name'
        )
    code = = filters.NumberFilter(
            field_name="company__code",
            label='code'
        )
    


class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name','last_name','code']
```

You can simply call your searchfilter set in views now It will do your work

Answer (score 1):

thats will better and will work i hope )

```
class SearchUserAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            q = request.query_params
            first_name = q.get('first_name')
            last_name = q.get('last_name')
            code = q.get('code')
            data = Person.objects.filter(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, company_code=code)
            data = [search_results]

            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        except Exception as e:
            return Response({"error": e}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

also you can easy add another fields to filter